# Return duration of an item from it'sits transactions, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, transactions, many-to-many

(posting again, last post did not include outgoing and was down voted)

**Situation**

There are two incoming stations and one outgoing station. Items are scanned in and out. I need to know how long an item was in the station. Let's consider 'in station' to be the time between it's incoming date scan and it's outgoing date scan.

**Problem**

1. An item can be (accidentally) scanned multiple times into either station (for this I was thinking of identifying if a scan was made the same day (not looking at hours) then return the earliest time scanned)
2. An item can come in an out from the station multiple times (multiple in and out scans)
3. If an item was scanned into both incoming locations, need to get the earliest time

Sample of Data..

```
╔═════════╦════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╗
║ Row_num ║ ItemID ║      Dates       ║  LocationName  ║   Type   ║
╠═════════╬════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ ItemA  ║ 1/7/20 12:49 PM  ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║       2 ║ ItemA  ║ 1/2/20 7:29 AM   ║ Incoming_Loc_A ║ Incoming ║
║       3 ║ ItemB  ║ 1/3/20 11:01 AM  ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║       4 ║ ItemB  ║ 1/2/20 4:57 PM   ║ Incoming_Loc_B ║ Incoming ║
║       5 ║ ItemB  ║ 1/2/20 5:01 PM   ║ Incoming_Loc_A ║ Incoming ║
║       6 ║ ItemB  ║ 12/12/19 5:58 PM ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║       7 ║ ItemB  ║ 12/12/19 5:57 PM ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║       8 ║ ItemB  ║ 5/20/19 10:19 AM ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║       9 ║ ItemC  ║ 1/9/20 9:20 AM   ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║      10 ║ ItemC  ║ 1/2/20 6:42 PM   ║ Incoming_Loc_A ║ Incoming ║
║      11 ║ ItemC  ║ 12/20/19 5:54 AM ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║      12 ║ ItemC  ║ 10/10/19 6:13 PM ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
║      13 ║ ItemC  ║ 10/5/19 7:00 PM  ║ Incoming_Loc_A ║ Incoming ║
║      14 ║ ItemC  ║ 7/16/19 9:18 AM  ║ Outgoing_Loc   ║ Outgoing ║
╚═════════╩════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I tried to provide every type of problem into the table distributed to the different  Items.

The perfect transaction is **ItemA**, it's so simple and clean, if they were all like this then I could just join the tables and pull them on separate columns.

**ItemB**, You'll notice this one was scanned to both of the incoming locations, but I only need to return one- the earliest it came in from that batch. Additionally, need to return the incoming that is after the oldest outgoing(12/12/19) and before the last outgoing(1/3/20).

**ItemC**, similar to the last statement for ItemB, this item came in and out from the locations twice. Need to get the incoming and outgoing pair that makes the most sense chronologically.

I don't know how hard this is to figure out, but I'm having a tough time finding a solution for it. I'm not sure how to squeeze in the incoming date between the outgoing.

Example of Output:
Need to get how many days each item was in the station. If the item has been in-n-out multiple times, need to pair the incoming and outgoing that makes the most sense chronologically. ItemC for example, has multiple incoming and outgoing dates, but I only need the dates that have a beginning and end as a pair.

```
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| ItemID |    Incoming     |     Outgoing     | Days in Station |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| ItemA  | 1/2/20 7:29 AM  | 1/7/20 12:49 PM  | 5.00            |
| ItemB  | 1/2/20 4:57 PM  | 1/3/20 11:01 AM  | 1.00            |
| ItemC  | 1/2/20 6:42 PM  | 1/9/20 9:20 AM   | 7.00            |
| ItemC  | 10/5/19 7:00 PM | 10/10/19 6:13 PM | 5.00            |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please don't post a second question the same, edit your original question. Once it is improved the downvotes maybe removed. But this will get downvoted as a duplicate.

Comment: As commented by @DaleK, this is exactly identical to your previous question. I closed it as duplicate, and answered your other question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you can do this without creating extra tables within your query.

If you are not aware of them it is pretty cool and will take your SQL level to the next level.

i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM WHERE ...)
```

At the very least you would want the following tables:
A table showing whether an item has been scanned more than once.
Order that table as such

Table 1A. Item; Number of times Outgoing; Date
Order it by Item and Date desc (earliest date will be shown)

Table 1B
Based off Table 1A takes the earliest date where number of items is more than one

Table 2A. Item. Number of times Incoming.
Order it by Item and Date desc (earliest date will be shown)

Table 2B
Based off Table 2A takes the earliest date where number of items is more than one

Use Tables 1B and 2B to derive your answer.

Someone else may be more patient and give a more refined answer but hope above helps.